# Doctrine query Builder case statement throw an unexpected syntax error

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm currently quit new with doctrine, and I've been trying for the last 2 hours to make a select to get the sum of a specific field  but only when a boolean is true, and then, another select for the sum of this field when the boolean is false

I tried to make my select like :

```
sum(case when (f.prevision = 1) then f.total end)
sum(case when (f.prevision = 0) then f.total end)
```

and then I'm also having others selects and join, but those ones aren't that important. The thing is that doctrine throw an error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 212: Error: Unexpected ')'
```

And I tried the select with native SQL by console like :

```
SELECT sum(case when prevision = 1 then total end)
from membre_facturation
GROUP BY id_utilisateur
```

and have no error, and even the expected result. Is something wrong with doctrine and case statement ?

Thanks in advance for your help. And sorry if some things are missing, I didn't want to write too much code, which would have been kind of "too much"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've been trying a bit more offline, then without seeing your answer. And it appears that in the case of the query builder, the ELSE statement isn't optional. I wrote my query like :

```
sum(case when (f.prevision = 1) then f.total else 0 end)
```

And it is actually working. I will also check the coalesce function. Maybe it will also work.
Or maybe I was doing something else wrong, but the thing is that adding the else statement sorted things out for me.

Any idea if one is faster than the other one ? From what I saw, "CASE" and "COALESCE" are quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than case, does this layout work for you?

```
select sum(f.total) 
from f
where f.prevision = 1
```

Comment: Of course I've been thinking about that. But actualy I have 2 selects, they will be like : 

`sum(case when (f.prevision = 1) then f.total end)`

`sum(case when (f.prevision = 0) then f.total end)`

Comment: Does this fit your case then:

select sum(f.total) ,f.prevision
from f
group by f.prevision.

Would be easier if you have an example result set

Comment: I didn't think of that, maybe it'll also work that way. I will give it a try too thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(m.prevision), 0) as sumOfPrevision
from membre_facturation as m
GROUP BY m.id_utilisateur
```

In Doctrine2:

```
$this->createQueryBuilder('m')
     ->select('coalesce(sum(m.prevision = 1), 0) as sumOfPrevision') ## for true
     | OR |
     ->select('coalesce(sum(m.prevision = 0), 0) as sumOfPrevision') ## for false
     ->orderBy('m.id_utilisateur')
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```

Comment: Hello again. After checking out your answer with my database. Your query actualy return the number of lines where m.prevision = 1 (or 0), which isn't exactly what I want. But thank you for your answer anyway.